# jQuery attaching map markers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a map where I can attach the markers. The image also zoom in and out on  a mouse scroll. The problem is that the markers doesn't flow with the zoom. Also the marker displays little off when clicked. Any idea?

```
<div class="custom"></div>
<div id="map1"></div>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#map1').html('<img src="http://www.newlondon-tours.com/public/maps/london-city-map-free-england.jpg" alt="custom" class="custom_img" style="position:absolute;z-index:1" />');
    $('.custom_img').wheelzoom();
$(".custom_img").click(function(e){
var offset_t = $(this).offset().top - $(window).scrollTop();
var offset_l = $(this).offset().left - $(window).scrollLeft();
var left = Math.round( (e.clientX - offset_l) );
var top = Math.round( (e.clientY - offset_t) );     

$('.custom').append('<p  style="z-index:11;font-size:100px;border:1px solid #000;border-radius: 10px;background:red;width:10px;height:10px;position:absolute;left:' + left + 'px;top:'+ top +'px" ></p>');              

          }); 

})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vm526/1/)

Comment: Sounds like you need to have a look at whatever library you're using that provides `wheelzoom()`.

Comment: make sense! I found it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need to have a look at whatever library you're using that provides `wheelzoom()`